# Adding multiple pointcut expressions in a single Advice in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to put multiple pointcut expressions for a single advice,
for eg, I want to call an advice for 2 methods of classA.
ClassA has two methods method1 and method2 and I am putting my point expression as,

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * ClassA.method1(..)) || " +
            "execution(public * ClassA.method2(..))")
 public void pointcutDefn() {}
```

Advice is defined below,

```
 @Around("pointcutDefn()")
 public void aroundAdvice(..) {
 ... 
 }
```

When the method1 or method2 executes, my around advice is not triggered at all.
Any help here.

Comment: I found the answer, the issue was not with the code. I did not give sufficient access permissions for the class, so the class was not loaded itself. After giving the permissions, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the issue was not with the code. I did not give sufficient access permissions for the class, so the class was not loaded itself. After giving the permissions, it worked fine.